# Casting a interface derived class to another derived class

Tags: c#, casting

I am trying to accomplish a way to cast a given object that is derived from an interface to a different type that is also derived from the same interface. This to prevent having to completely rebuild the object.

```
interface IItem
{
}

class FryingPan : IItem
{
}

class CookingPan : IItem
{
}
```

But here is the catch, I don't 'know' what type I am casting to. I only know by a type variable. This is set from a combobox.

```
Type SelectedItem { get; set; }
```

Can this be done ( preferably without having to implement `IConvertable` )

Comment: What do you hope to achieve by casting, if you don't know the type at compile-time?

Comment: To put it in a simple way; sorting. All Items are stored in a list and each item will be placed, shown and interacted with slightly differently between eachother but essentially all do the same. The item can, or well should, be interchangeable between other types

Comment: I think you should describe what you want to achieve so that we can give you another point of view than the one you are seeing the problem right now, which seems a bit 'twisted'

Comment: @Nensec: Sounds like both of them should implement `IComparable<IItem>`, at which point no casting is required.

Answer (score 3):

If what you are trying to do is cast CookingPan to FryingPan, it can't be done. One would have to derive from the other to cast. Imagine;

```
interface IFruit
{ }

class Apple : IFruit
{ }

class Orange : IFruit
{ }
```

Obviously, an apple can never be an orange, and vice-versa. However, you *could* cast either an Apple or an Orange to IFruit, as they both share that common ancestor. Or, if you are a mad scientist, perhaps you could **convert** an apple to an orange somehow. ;-)

I would say that you are approaching your problem in the wrong way. If you need to perform some specific action on an IItem depending on its .Type, then you already have that information. If you need some common sort criteria, consider moving it to the base class/interface as a common ancestor for all derived types.

Comment: What if you have IPerson - an interface for a person and two classes Employee:IPeople and NotEmployee:IPeople and want to convert a person from employee to not employee?

Comment: As long as you only want to interact with the objects via the IPeople interface, it doesn't matter what the concrete types are (except in runtime behaviour)